# Add Paging to URL JSON Request in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

How can I add Paging to my JSON parser code?

```
function appendPost(__, post) {
  var title = $('<div/>')
    .addClass('post_title')
    .text(post.post_title);
  var content = $('<div/>')
    .addClass('post_content')
    .text(post.post_content);
  $('#test')
    .append(title)
    .append('<br/>')
    .append(content);
}

function processResults(parsed_json) {
  var posts = parsed_json.result || [];
  $('#test').empty();
  $.each(posts, appendPost);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.getJSON("https//website-API-json.com/string")
    .then(processResults);
});
```

I've been trying to figure it out, but can't seem to get it right.

The JSON result has server paging, but I can't seem to get a dynamic way to change/request a new page of results.

Any Ideas?

Here's the output of the JSON

```
{  
  "respond":1,
  "paging":{  
    "stillmore":0,
    "perpage":10,
    "callpage":1,
    "next":2,
    "previous":0,
    "pages":1,
    "result":"1"
  },
  "message":"",
  "result":[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to build a cache object to store responses. Then if you already have data cached when moving paging backwards you have instant data access rather than needing to call server again.

```
var cache={
   activeRequest:null,
   pages:{}
}

function cacheResponse(resp) {
    // update cache with new response
    cache.pages[parsed_json.paging.callingpage] = parsed_json;
    $.extend(cache.activeRequest, parsed_json);
}

function getData(page) {
    $.getJSON("https//website-API-json.com/string?page=" + page).done(function (response) {
        processResults(response);
        cacheResponse(response);
    });    
}
```

Then in your paging logic:

```
if(cache.pages[ page_number]){
   // use existing data when we have it available
   processResults(cache.pages[ page_number]);
}else{
   // otherwise get from server
   getData(page_number);
}
```

This is pretty loose and needs a bit of validation of values but should give you concept to start from.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the submit. I'll test it out when when I get a chance later today.